# Teams App development - Fluent UI React Components v9 vs Fluent UI React Northstar

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

According to this ***https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui*** repository, there are many UI library from fluent UI.

***@fluentui/react-northstar*** library is used to develop Teams App development. but I have no idea why another similar ***Fluent UI React Components v9*** library is there.
What library is recommended  for Teams app development ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fluentui/react-northstar) should answer your question.  In short, React Components v9 will eventually supersede react-northstar.